# How to fix Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.Long

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following in my interface that extends `MongoRepository`:

```
@Query(value = "{ '_id': { '$in': ?0} }, { '_id': 1}")
List<Long> getExistingIds(List<String> ids);
```

When I run this, I get:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find
PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.Long
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify a projection using Json:

```java
@Query(value = "{ '_id': { '$in': ?0} }", fields = "{ '_id': 1}")
List<YourEntity> getExistingIds(List<Long> ids);
```

- YourEntity will contain only specified fields.
- Also note that you have `Long` id, so I changed the type of `ids` parameter accordingly.

A relevant piece of documentation: [MongoDB JSON-based Query Methods and Field Restriction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based)

Comment: Yeah, I found that out already. Too bad it is this way. Kind of constraining a bit. I'll give you credit for this answer anyway as it is definitely correct. Thanks!

Comment: But the answer is not what you asked for. Useless either you cannot or can return a list of Longs. He didn't say if it was possible.